# How to POST a collection of domain objects with JAX-RS grails

Tags: rest, grails, jax-rs

I'm using the JAX-RS plugin with grails (Version 0.8) and I have a domain class the represents a single data point

```
class DataPoint {

   static hasOne = [user: User]
   int time
   int accelerationX
   int accelerationY
   int accelerationZ
   ....
}
```

now I want to be able to POST a collection of these as to reduce the number of hits to the server (we sample @ a high frequency).

I know that that JAX-RS plugin does not support Domain Class Collections as an input so I wrote a single Wrapper in src/groovy

```
public class DataPoints {

   List<DataPoint> data = new ArrayList<>();

   public void add(DataPoint dataPoint) {
       data.add(dataPoint)
   }

   public List<DataPoint> getData() {
       return data
   }
}
```

I used the generated Resource class

```
@Path('/api/data')
@Consumes(['application/xml', 'application/json'])
@Produces(['application/xml', 'application/json'])
class DataPointCollectionResource {

   def dataPointResourceService

   @POST
   Response create(DataPoints dto) {
       created dataPointResourceService.create(dto) //overwritten to take wrapper class
   }

   @GET
   Response readAll() {
       DataPoints dataPoints = new DataPoints();
       DataPoint.findAll().each {
           dataPoints.add(it)
       }
       ok dataPoints
   }
}
```

However this fails to work.

I tried posting some xml

```
<dataPoints>
  <data>
    <dataPoint>
      <accelerationX>0</accelerationX>
      <accelerationY>0</accelerationY>
      <accelerationZ>0</accelerationZ>
      <user id="1"/>
    </dataPoint>
    <dataPoint>
      <accelerationX>0</accelerationX>
      <accelerationY>0</accelerationY>
      <accelerationZ>0</accelerationZ>
      <user id="1"/>
    </dataPoint>
  </data>
</dataPoints>
```

using curl

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" --request POST -d <xml data> <path to resource>
```

Error I got was:

```
ERROR container.ContainerRequest  - A message body reader for Java class 
com.wristband.atlas.SensorDataPoints, and Java type class     
com.wristband.atlas.SensorDataPoints, and MIME media type application/xml was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
```

Trying to do a GET on the Resource gives me pretty much the same thing.

I know I'm missing something because I've done this in java before I just don't know what config I'm missing.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@GET
Response readAll() {
   ok DataPoint.findAll()
}
```